# How can i connect Navigation Drawer to activity without using Fragments

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer

Im trying to connect Navigation Drawer to activity. I already have some Activity that extends AppCompatActivity. but in tutorial, Activity you want to connect navigation drawer should extends Fragments. Is there any way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home) {
            Intent secIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.livestream) {
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextIntent);
}

        mDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use intent for change each activity from navigation drawer, but the consequence of use activity is the navigation is only in activity where navigation is putted, you should use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in action bar to make it easy for back to `MainActivity`